# Elasticsearch bucket union

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this example list of documents:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test_data/test_row/_bulk?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{ "index": {}}
{ "value": 1, "user_id": 1, "profiler_id": 1}
{ "index": {}}
{ "value": 3, "user_id": 1, "profiler_id": 1}
{ "index": {}}
{ "value": 3, "user_id": 1, "profiler_id": 2}
{ "index": {}}
{ "value": 1, "user_id": 2, "profiler_id": 1}
{ "index": {}}
{ "value": 1, "user_id": 2, "profiler_id": 2}
{ "index": {}}
{ "value": 1, "user_id": 3, "profiler_id": 1}
{ "index": {}}
{ "value": 2, "user_id": 3, "profiler_id": 2}
{ "index": {}}
{ "value": 3, "user_id": 3, "profiler_id": 2}
{ "index": {}}
{ "value": 2, "user_id": 4, "profiler_id": 1}
{ "index": {}}
{ "value": 1, "user_id": 4, "profiler_id": 2}
{ "index": {}}
{ "value": 3, "user_id": 4, "profiler_id": 2}
'
```

I want to count all users that answered profiler_id=1 and value=1 AND profiler_id=2 and value 1 or 2. This means that only users 2 and 3 match the criteria for both.

I know how to make a bucket aggregation on terms and count matching documents per profiler_id but is there a way in Elasticsearch to count users matching BOTH criteria at once?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "profiler_id": 1
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "value": 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "profiler_id": 2
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "value": [
                    1,
                    2
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "profiler_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "type_count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "user_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Would give me the counts separately per `profiler_id` which is not what I want. I'm not sure how to count users that have documents intersecting in both buckets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I looked for required indexing user objects and then indexing their profilers as child documents. This way I could write following example query to get the results I want:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "country": "US"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "gender": "m"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "2017-10-01"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date_of_birth": {
              "gte": "1987-11-09",
              "lte": "1999-11-09"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "user_profiler",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "profiler_id": 6
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "terms": {
                            "answer_value": [
                              3,4,5
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "must_not": [],
                "should": []
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "user_profiler",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "profiler_id": 3
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "terms": {
                            "answer": [
                              1
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "must_not": [],
                "should": []
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to count the number of *unique* users that match those criteria? If so you can just move your `should` clauses into the `must` parameter (forcing an AND) and use the cardinality aggregation on the `user_id` field

If not, can you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: Yes, thats what I'm trying to do, I don't think moving to `must` solves anything because, as far as I understand a single document will have to match both criteria that are mutually exclusive.

It will give 0 documents because if document looks like this `{ "value": 1, "user_id": 1, "profiler_id": 1}`  then it can't match BOTH `profiler_id=1` AND `profiler_id=2` at same time.